# Fastest way to rename / move thousands of files

Tags: windows, batch

I have a `extFAT` external drives that contains backup results from experiments, under a folder hierarchy. I want to flatten this folder directory by renaming all files as follows:

```
results/a/b/c/result.json -> results/a_b_c_result.json
```

I already have a python script to do this:

```
for dp, dn, fns in os.walk('ogsn'):
    for fn in fns:
        path = os.path.join(dp, fn)
        newpath = '_'.join(os.path.normpath(dp).split(os.sep) + [fn])
        os.rename(path, newpath)
     if i % 1000 == 0:
         print(i, dp)
     i += 1
```

The problem is that I have about a million files... And this is taking forever.

Is there a way to speed things up?

Comment: Do you at least have write caching enabled for this disk?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a PowerShell one liner, recursing from `X:\results` with a reative path

```
Set-Location X:\results;Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Name -File | Select-Object -First 20 | Move-Item -Destination {$_ -replace '\\','_'} -WhatIf
```

If the output looks OK, remove `| Select-Object -First 20` and the trailing `-WhatIf`

But keep in mind that **ONE** folder containing a million files could slow down **ANY** further action even more.

Comment: Thanks. This does not seem faster than the python alternative, althgouht it's simpler. But you're right than a single folder with 1000k files isn't that great... I have to find a way to organize these results more efficiently.